# no route to host (host unreachable) since new update

Tags: android, android-studio

since the new Android Studio Update (like 25. September 2018) in every project i try to open the gradle build fails with the error message: no route to host (host unreachable).
Also, the project menue on the left side of AS looks weird, the java classes are hidden behind 6 folders, same for the xml

(i use ubuntu)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Henry no im not